Send matching command to a discord channel with selenium
I want to send a command /richest to discord channel like this:

Here is my code:
# Send message
input_box = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, input_box_xpath)
input_box.send_keys('/richest')  #
time.sleep(2)  # Wait for 2 seconds after writing message
input_box.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(1)  # Wait for 1 second after pressing enter

But it doesn't work. I always stuck at this one:


It is suggesting available commands with the given keyword so you can add 2 lines of code to select /richest command and click on it after sending keys. Then it may work

Thank you. I tried to simulation keyboard and it works.
